# Dual Boot Kubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 and LUKS not working correctly

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, encryption, luks

I want to dual boot kubuntu and windows 10, but both OS partitions should be encrypted. After disabling secure boot I installed kubuntu 20.04.1 on a partition and could boot into it or windows 10 just fine. Everything worked as expected.

As a next step I wanted to install Kubuntu on a encrypted partition with LUKS. I managed to install and boot Kubuntu 20.04 after following these guides: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/System_verschl%C3%BCsseln/

The weird issue with both processes: I can boot, decrypt the drive with my passphrase and everything seems to work fine. Except most devices do not work: WiFi, Bluetooth, Thunderbolt Dock, audio. Alls of these are completely absent in this encrypted kubuntu but worked fine in the same before encrypting. They also worked just fine in the live version I booted from a usb stick.

I use a Lenovo T490, secure boot is disable, TPM is on but not used for LUKS.

Any ideas?